# C# Chaining multiple LINQ contains to search for user

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-core

I am trying to add a user to a team by searching through a list of users.

I am using linq to search through the data to find a match based on a number of fields

```
data = data.Where(x =>
                    x.Name.ToLower().Contains(filter) ||
                    x.Surname.ToLower().Contains(filter) ||
                    x.PhoneNumber.ToLower().Contains(filter) ||
                    x.Email.ToLower().Contains(filter) ||
                    x.AthleteTeams.All(x => x.Team.Name.Contains(filter)) ||
                    x.AthleteTeams.All(x => x.Athlete.AthleteGender.Equals(filter)) ||
                    x.AthleteTeams.All(x => x.Athlete.AthleteRace.Equals(filter))
                );
```

However, the results work only with name, surname and email.

When all the fields are searched it gives back seemingly random users instead of those that meet the specified filter

Comment: _it gives back seemingly random users instead of those that meet the specified filter_ --> Can you provide a specific example scenario and provide values for `data`, `filter`, expected output and actual output?

Comment: Are you sure you need `All` and not `Any`. Note that `All` for empty collection is always true in LINQ-to-Objects.

Comment: Data would be a list of users with a name. Email address phone number etc. Filter would be what you type into the search bar. Such as a person or typing "Jo" should bring up a "John" but instead brings up things like "Amy"

Comment: @MylesLouw That is not specific enough example data. Seeing as you have a lot of OR conditions, there are so many potential matches that can be made. Also, you use `.ToLower()` some places, and others not. Is that intended? Has `filter` been `.ToLower()`ed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess that you dont want to find all users which `AthleteTeams` have ALL the same team-name, for example. That would mean you have multiple teams with a similar name.

I guess that you actually want to find all users which `AthleteTeams` contain at least ONE team with matching name, for example. So use `Any` and also use only one query of  `AthleteTeams` instead of three:

```
 ....
 x.AthleteTeams.Any(x => x.Team.Name.Contains(filter)
                     ||  x.Athlete.AthleteGender.Equals(filter)
                     ||  x.Athlete.AthleteRace.Equals(filter))
```

However, i find this filter logic strange and error-prone. You will have a slow search performance and many false matches, because always something matches and the user doesn't know why. Better provide a search through the most common properties like the names and phone-number, don't start to search before the user enters at least 3 characters and provide a specific team-search.

Answer (score 2):

> However, the results work only with name, surname and email.

I think `PhoneNumber` should be fine too.

> When all the fields are searched it gives back seemingly random users instead of those that meet the specified filter

`Enumerable.All` for empty collection will always be true:

```cs
Console.WriteLine(new int[]{}.All(i => false)); // prints True
```

Try using something like:

```cs
data = data.Where(x =>
    ... || (x.AthleteTeams.Any() && (
    x.AthleteTeams.All(x => x.Team.Name.Contains(filter)) ||
    x.AthleteTeams.All(x => x.Athlete.AthleteGender.Equals(filter)) ||
    x.AthleteTeams.All(x => x.Athlete.AthleteRace.Equals(filter))))
);
```

Also possibly you actually need `Any` instead of `All` in the first place:

```cs
data = data.Where(x =>
    ... 
    || x.AthleteTeams.Any(x => x.Team.Name.Contains(filter) 
             || x.Athlete.AthleteGender.Equals(filter)
             ||  x.Athlete.AthleteRace.Equals(filter))
);
```